# Is it $f(x)\frac{x}{x^2+1}$ onto and/or one to one?

Tags: functions

Define  $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ by
$$f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2+1}$$

Is $f$ injective (one to one)?
Is $f$ surjective (onto)?

---

**My Attempt:** I filled if set $x$ as $1,2,3,4,5$ and $f(x)$ each got a unique value so my answer is yes its both injective and surjective, but I'd like to see how someone else works it out.

Comment: Hmmm. It is almost inversion, which is a bijection from R-{0} to itself

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  What have you tried?  Do you know what injective/surjective mean in terms of the *graph* of a function? Have you tried graphing the function?

Comment: It is important that when asking questions, you provide some amount of [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) rather than simply copying the problem statement.

Comment: yes one to one means each x has an f(x) and i think onto means no y is left without an x. I filled if set x as 1,2,3,4,5 and f(x) each got a unique value so my answer is yes its both injective and surjective, just getting feedback. i "simply copied" the problem statement to see how someone else works it out

Comment: Well, as you can see [in the link from my last comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), we expect a little bit more to go into the questions asked here.  In the future, consider including information like that (the conclusion you reached and/or what you tried) along with the question.

Comment: okay, i did not understand that. Clearly, i reached the wrong solution, can you explain where i went wrong.

Comment: Consider its reciprocal, x+1/x, over R-{0}. It goes from increasing to decreasing so it is not injective. Thus neither is f. It also cannot be surjective because either x or 1/x has absolute value greater than 1 so the sum has absolute value greater than one. Thus neither is f.

Answer (score 1):

Checking a few values never hurts (it's an easy way to show that the function fails to be injective), but that won't be enough to prove that the function is injective.  Also, it does nothing to address whether or not the function is surjective.

When it comes to (continuous) functions $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, the best way to verify injectivity/surjectivity is to consider its *graph*.  An injective function is one whose graph passes the horizontal line test.  A surjective function is one whose graph "hits every $y$-value".

One of the immediate features you'll notice is that the graph has horizontal asymptotes to the right and left at $y = 0$. This is enough for us to determine that $f(x)$ can't possibly hit every $y$-value, since it eventually has to "come back down".  So, $f$ is **not surjective**.

In particular, we can show that over $[0,\infty)$, $f(x)$ increases towards some maximum value, then settles down towards its asymptote.  Of course, the graph never hits a $y$-value above its maximum, which is another way to conclude that it's not surjective.

For a particular example, show that the equation
$$
\frac{x}{x^2 + 1} = 2
$$
has no solution.

We can also see that, because the graph hits a maximum and then comes back down, it won't pass the horizontal line test either, which means that it's **not injective**.  In particular, if we choose any value between $0$ and the maximum, we'll find that $f$ hits that $y$-value twice: once on the way up, and once on the way down.

If you prefer to think of it another way, check that the equation
$$
\frac{x}{x^2 + 1} = \frac 25
$$
has two solutions.

Comment: how can you solve it without thinking of the graph? im terrible with graphs

Comment: @Yeuhhh graphing the function (or sketching the graph) is definitely the most universal approach for considering functions of the form $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$.  Of course, there are a few "tricks" that work for this particular function.  I would say that the quickest graph-free approach in this case is to note that this function can be written as 
$$
f(x) = \left[x + \frac 1x\right]^{-1}
$$
we can quickly see that it won't be injective (for example, since $f(2) = f(1/2)$), and with a little work we can come up with an upper bound, which means it won't be surjective.

Comment: @Yeuhh It comes down to this: plugging in $x = 1,2,3,4,\dots$ won't work because we don't have a function over $\Bbb N$, we have a function over $\Bbb R$.  The only way to "see what's happening" to the infinitely many values on the number line is to graph the function.

Comment: In fact, if we define $f:\Bbb N \to \Bbb R$ or $f:\Bbb Z \to \Bbb R$ with the same rule, then the resulting function will be injective (but will still not be surjective).

Answer (score 0):

To prove $f$ is injective, you must show that if $f(a)=f(b)$ then $a=b$.
To prove $f$ is not injective, you must show there exist $a,b$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$ and $a≠b$.
To prove $f$ is surjective, you must show that for any $c ∈ \mathbb{R}$ there exists $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$ such that $c=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$.
To prove $f$ is not surjective, you must show that the range of $f$ is not $(-\infty,\infty)$.

You can set up the proofs from here.

Comment: Your answer seems to imply that the function is injective and surjective, which is not the case.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Does $f(x)$ have an absolute maximum or a minimum?  If it is bounded above, then there is a $y \in \mathbb R$ such that $\forall x \in \mathbb R, \, f(x) < y.$

What does that imply about injectiveity, surjectivity?

Next question, does $f(x)$ pass the horizontal line test?
If it does, what does that say about the properties above?